# How can I delete old entries from an excel table (automatically) when I upload new data?

Tags: excel, automation, pivot-table, excel-tables

I have a query related to excel tables that I use to build my pivot table. Now we know the excel table automatically gets updated when we add new data. But my issue here is let's say, for example, I sold 20 books this month and the details of these books I have copied and pasted it from another excel sheet are in range A1:E20 in my current sheet, next month I sell 25 books, now the range becomes A1:E25, the excel table gets updated. Now the month after that I just sell 15 books, therefore, the range should be A1: E15. If I paste the info, the remaining data from A16:E20 will still exist and I don't want them to still remain in the table.

Is there any way to automate this?

I don't want to manually delete it all the time.